# Modify HtmlHelper value when using JS clone.node

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I have a table where a user inputs info for the DB. The 2 fields here are
"type" and "name". Type must be either "L" or "S", but it is depicted to user as "Large" or "Small".

Say the user needs a new row for more data. I have 2 buttons, "Large" and "Small", that
fire the same JS function to create a new row. I want the value from the button to be
input into the new row in the type column. How would I accomplish this?

I'd like to do this using the clone.node function somehow, but the HtmlHelpers are throwing me off as well.

```
<tr id=rowToClone>
<td style="width:30px">
                @Html.DropDownList("manifests.Type",
                    new SelectList(new List<Object>
                    {
                        new { value = "L", text = "Large"},
                        new { value = "S", text = "Small"},
                    },
                    "value",
                    "text"
                    )
                    )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("manifests.Name")
            </td>
</tr>

<input type="button" value="Add Large" id="btAddL" style="display: none; float:left" onclick="addRow('L')"/>
<input type="button" value="Add Small" id="btAddS" style="display: none; float: left" onclick="addRow('S')"/>

<script>
    function addRow(type) {
    document.getElementById("btAddL").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btAddS").style.display = "none";

    var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
    var table = document.getElementById("tableToClone");
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.display = "table-row";
    /*clone.node.td.type = type;*/
    
    table.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the HtmlHelpers"? is that part of ASP.NET

Comment: added "ASP.NET" as a tag but you should figure out if this problem is specific to the ASP.NET feature or the JS cloning.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is purely from the perspective of the JS, I'm not sure about those ASP.NET helpers at the top...

I think that what you want *within* the clone you're trying to reach for the `<td>` cell? is that right?

I imagine this is what you are thinking because you've commented out  `clone.node.td`

Probably you need to find the `<td>` element itself

```
var td_element = clone.querySelectorAll('td:first-child')
td_element.type = type; // this line makes no sense as <td> elements do not have types so maybe the line above should select for a kind of an HTML element that has a type
```

If the thing you want to clone is pretty small it could be easy (and a good exercise) just to create new elements instead of the cloning.

https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom#querySelectorAll

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_type.asp

Comment: ok yeah, I am trying to select the first <td> element. After reading the article provided, I'm still unclear on how to specify the element. Can you help me there?